# NFC forced rescan

Tags: android, nfc

If a tag is already scanned, Android can start my activity, so good. Now I did a new activity started from the user, to allow the user to write the tag. When the activity is already open, I can receive the intent from the system only if the user re-scan the tag even if the phone is *already* on the tag, is there a way to force the rescan?

Comment: My guess is that there isn't -- I would expect to see something on `NfcAdapter`, or maybe `NfcManager` for that, and I don't.

Comment: You can keep the [tech](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/package-summary.html) object between activities and do whatever you want with this. No reason to rescan the tag!

Comment: @VGe0rge Yep, but I don't have any tag object. The new activity is started by the user at any time.

Answer (score 1):

You can't "rescan" the tag, this is not possible because of how the NFC works. When you have the NFC enabled in your phone the NFC antenna is always searching for a tag. So rescan the tag doesn't make any sense.

You have two options, the first one as I have pointed in my comment is sharing the Tag object between your activities and do whatever you want with that.

The second option if you want to write the tag after the user has opened your application is using the [onNewIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent). This way you can capture the Intent that will be sent from the android system after the user has pointed the NFC tag close to the NFC antenna.